# Send Email to the Owner in lightning

Tags: administration, leads, lead-conversion

I can see this checkbox on classic, but how can I make this checkbox visible in lightning? Please help. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in lightning I guess. We have an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdgr5UAB/send-email-to-the-ownerlead-convertion-lightning) logged already for this. You can upvote this so salesforce may consider to deliver in future releases accordingly

You may have to develop some Flow to send an email to owner .

Comment: Is there any workaround? Please let me know.

Comment: As mentioned above did you try achieving this using some flow?